# html5 canvas; rotated image flashes in ie

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, rotation

There is a strange bug in IE (sometimes in firefox too).
I can't describe it well, but the rotated images are flashing if I use `fillText`, after the rotation. Even strange, if I use `strokeText`, there is no flashing.
I created a fiddle about it: http://jsfiddle.net/ncscwfwp/1/

Tested on win 8.1

- ie11: buggy
- firefox 33: sometimes buggy
- chrome 38: not buggy

Comment: I'm not seeing flashing in IE11 or FF.

Comment: I am not seeing any flashing in Internet Explorer or FF either. Can you access remoteIE (http://remote.modern.ie) and see if you repro the issue there as well?

Comment: I just checked in another computer, and there wasn't flashing

Comment: @JonathanSampson tested on remoteIE, it works correctly, no flashing.

Comment: @GáborBokodi It's probably your machine then. Be sure to update all drivers and stay as fresh as you can be. If you'd like more info into your hardware, etc., run `dxdiag` from the Run window.

Comment: @JonathanSampson maybe, but i saw this flashing in my colleague's laptop too. That's why i was sure about this is a browser bug. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @GáborBokodi Run dxdiag on your colleague's machine too. Look for similarities; this doesn't appear to be a browser issue, but I won't dispute your experiences.

Comment: @JonathanSampson my english not so good (as you can see), so maybe there is a misunderstanding. I mean, I think you are right about this is not a browser issue.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I just installed some optional windows update, and the problem solved. I'd like to accept your solution: "Be sure to update all drivers". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not easily reproducible by others, nor was it reproducible via the [remoteIE](http://remote.modern.ie). As a result, a suggestion was made to update all drivers and see if the issue would then be resolved.

The author, in the comments above, stated that running Windows Update (and installing all updates, including optional updates) appears to have in fact resolved the issue.